# Nested CMake projects multiple definition error when adding header-only library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ library organized like:

```
Library/
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp
    src/
        file1.cpp
    include/
        file1.h
    Domains/
        CMakeLists.txt
        BlackJack/
            CMakeLists.txt
            src/
                foo1.cpp
            include/
                foo1.h
        ...
    libs/
        tapkee/
            CMakeLists.txt
            include/
                foo.hpp
         ....
```

Each library(i.e. Domains) contains linking and simple code for organizational purposes:

```
project(Domains)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_subdirectory(IDomain)
add_subdirectory(Blackjack)

add_library(Domains STATIC)
target_link_libraries(Domains IDomain BLACKJACK)
```

Each sub-library (i.e. Blackjack) has a really simple CMakeLists.txt that just compiles the library (add_library).

This has been working just fine, until now.

I'm adding a third-party library (http://tapkee.lisitsyn.me/). This is a header-only library. It looks like CMake doesn't support this, but I found some work-arounds. I create a empty dummy.cpp file. Here is the CMakeLists for the third-party library:

```
project (TAPKEE)
file(GLOB TAPKEE_INCLUDE
    "include/tapkee/*.hpp"
    "include/tapkee/callbacks/*.hpp"
    "include/tapkee/defines/*.hpp"
    "include/tapkee/external/*.hpp"
    "include/tapkee/neighbors/*.hpp"
    "include/tapkee/parameters/*.hpp"
    "include/tapkee/routines/*.hpp"
    "include/tapkee/traits/*.hpp"
    "include/tapkee/utils/*.hpp"
)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} header_only_BS.cpp ${TAPKEE_INCLUDE})
```

Here is the weird thing: My main.cpp and anything in the root src directory can include this tapkee library just fine, but none of the sub-libraries can (i.e. BlackJack). I get thousands of redefinition linker errors for the functions within tapkee.

Here is an example of the top-level CMakeLists:

```
project(ManifoldLearning)
#Root
set(SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
set(INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

#Domains
set(BLACKJACK_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Domains/Blackjack/include)

set(TAPKEE_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/tapkee/include/)

include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIR} ${SRC_DIR})
include_directories(${TAPKEE_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${BLACKJACK_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(Domains)
#add_subdirectory(libs/tapkee)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST} ${HEADER_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Domains)
```

I've been stuck on this for days, and any help/advice would be appreciated.

**Update**: I've removed the inclusion of the tapkee CMakeLists.txt (add_subdirectory) as per Antonio's direction. I still get redefinition errors, which I find strange. It's now not compiled anywhere and only included in BlackJack/src/foo1.cpp

Comment: It is unclear from the code you provide who links with `TAPKEE` and where it is done. Please, simplify your code (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and provide more of it.

Comment: @curranw If you have a header only library, then you don't need to build it. So, remove your workaround (`TAPKEE` target), make sure your projects can locate the header files, and you should get rid of the redefinition errors.

Comment: Made my example CMakeLists more general and removed the tapkee add_subdirectory call. It still has redefinition errors. It is only included in one cpp file (which is only included by the main.cpp).